# Android ORMlite performance problems with queryForAll()

Tags: android, ormlite, performance

Well, like the title says, i got some performance problems while executing queryForAll on a DAO object with ormLite (with android, if it should matter).

The only thing i am actually doing is to execute this:

> this.getHelper().getActivityDao().queryForAll(); (where this.getHelper() returns the database-helper which is extending from the OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class)

This single line needs actually round about 14 seconds to execute... Well, the "Activity" entity got about 80 fields and queryForAll returns a array with a length of 74 objects, but still - this can´t be normal, can it?

(For the Calendar fields i am using the

> @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)

annotation, i am not sure, if this is the right annotation for calendar fields or if it could result in performance issues...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This single line needs actually round about 14 seconds to execute... Well, the "Activity" entity got about 80 fields and queryForAll returns a array with a length of 74 objects, but still - this can´t be normal, can it?

A `queryForAll()` should not take a long time unless, as you might suspect, you have some *large* number of objects in your table -- or a large amount of data in each object.  In that case, `queryForAll()` has to basically dump the entire table and create a large number of objects.

For larger queries it is recommended to use iterators instead of dumping the whole table:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/iterator

For example, you can run through all of the objects in the query like this:

```
// page through all of the accounts in the database
for (Account account : accountDao) {
   // do something with each account here
}
```

Comment: @Above, no i got no foreign objects or automatically refreshing collections.
But it seems that the system is quite faster, if i use the iterator, instead of the queryOfAll method from the DAO... i also realized, that it´s also faster, if i just use the application on the android device, instead of debugging it through my pc. So the query needs at all now like 1-2 seconds and round about 7-8 seconds, if i go through debug mode in eclipse... Should be ok.

Comment: Good.  There _is_ a performance penalty to use ORMLite but making good decisions about calls will improve matters @user1502353.

Comment: Hi Gray! Can you give some short advice how to use ormlite iterator with android ListAdapter? or probably CursorAdapter?

Comment: I can't @deviant since I'm not an Android programmer.  I would suggest that you post this question to the ORMLite Android list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-android

Answer (score 1):

Does your class in question have foreign objects or collections that you're automatically refreshing with the ORM? By that, I mean members annotated with `foreignAutoRefresh = true` or collections annotated with `@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)` for example. These annotations will execute more queries on your behalf.

If that's the case, you may be unintentionally pulling back more data than you think. In that case, I would use `queryRaw()` and write a join statement by hand for your needed data.